# How to add extra sign to already existing x-ticks label matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently, my histogram plot's x-tick labels are [200.  400.  600.  800. 1000. 1200. 1400.]. It represents the rate in dollars. I want to add $ in prefix of these ticks like [$200  $400  $600  $800 $1000 $1200 $1400].

I tried this `axs.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()` to fetch x-tick labels and `axs.xaxis.set_ticks([f"${amount:.0f}" for amount in axs[0, 1].xaxis.get_majorticklocs()])` to set the updated one. I understand that It will throw error as x-tick labels are now string.

Need help! kindly assist how can I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use automatic `StrMethodFormatter` like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(100*np.random.rand(20))

# Use automatic StrMethodFormatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter('${x:1.2f}')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! it worked. It is always great to know multiple solutions for a problem.

Comment: @ApaarBawa I prefer this over my solution. You should mark that as accepted answer since it avoids the extra list comprehension

Comment: Got it! @Rabinzel

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
x = [*range(200,1600,200)]
y = [*range(7)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xticks(ticks=x, labels=[f"${num}" for num in x])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [`set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html), which says:

> Set the xaxis' labels with list of string labels.

Here you want to set the ticks to `[200. 400. 600. 800. 1000. 1200. 1400.]` and the labels to your string values to ensure it is all aligned.